# TwelveMonkeys 3.1.1: PSD file ImageIO.read gives java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of PackBits stream

Tags: java, twelvemonkeys

I am trying to convert a PSD file (500+ MB in size) which yields to this exception:

```
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of PackBits stream
    at com.twelvemonkeys.io.enc.PackBitsDecoder.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at com.twelvemonkeys.io.enc.PackBitsDecoder.decode(Unknown Source)
    at com.twelvemonkeys.io.enc.DecoderStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at com.twelvemonkeys.io.enc.DecoderStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readShort(DataInputStream.java:313)
    at com.twelvemonkeys.imageio.plugins.psd.PSDImageReader.read16bitChannel(Unknown Source)
    at com.twelvemonkeys.imageio.plugins.psd.PSDImageReader.readImageData(Unknown Source)
    at com.twelvemonkeys.imageio.plugins.psd.PSDImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1308)
```

Could anybody please suggest a solution for this? Or, at least, a reason why it yields this exception (maybe newer version of photoshop?).

**UPDATE:**

Here is the link for the PSD file I used:
[heavy.psd](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx8GyTBfuSFuZEgwRl9vYXdLX1k/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please attach (link) the file in question, and I'll tell you. ;-)

Comment: Hey @haraldK, thanks for reply. I have attached a link to PSD file I was trying to convert. Moreover, I am using *Java 8* with `TwelveMonkeys 3.1.1`. Please tell me if there is any other info I can provide to help you  analyze the problem.

Comment: Can you open this PSD file in Photoshop? At least I can't open this file (properly) in any of the standard tools in OS X, like Preview. To me, it seems like the file is corrupted.

Comment: Oh, I see. Actually I can open this file in Photoshop CS 6 (Extended). If any of the tools at your disposal can't open it, then that explains it. Can you please name the tools you are using on your machine?

Comment: Actually, I think it could be a bug in the code. I'm investigating...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here's the issue:

The PSD in question is 16 bit per sample, and uses PackBits compression. For some reason, I have had no test samples with this specific configuration, so there's been a bug there for ages.

For PackBits-compressed PSDs, there's a list of each row's byte count (for easier random access I guess) at the beginning of the file. I had this value multiplied by 2 for 16 bit and 4 for 32 bit samples, but obviously a byte count is just a byte count, regardless of if the samples are 2 or 4 bytes...

Now, when I changed this, the image is read without error. However, this PSD seems to be stored without a "merged" layer (this is what most software that claims to read PSD is able to display), yet it has 7 channels, of which 4 are alpha channels. When I open it, it just comes out mostly transparent (opening in OS X's Preview, it comes out all transparent).

The above fix is now pushed to the master branch on GitHub.